# Disable button on conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a buttons which are displayed from sql query:

```
     $username = new User();
    $name = $username->data()->username;
    $sql1 = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT names FROM list WHERE username = '$name'");
   if (!$sql1->count()) {
        echo 'No data';
    } else {
        foreach ($sql1->results() as $sql1) {
            ?>

                                    <p><button class="" > <?php echo $sql1->names; ?></button></p>
                                    <?php                            
                             }
                          }
```

This displays two buttons which match the conditions from the query, so I'm trying to disable one of the displayed buttons if it doesn't match another condition.
For example, there are two buttons, John and Poodle. And a query to match if one of the buttons is an animal.

So if the button john does not match the query, it should be disabled.

Comment: Well, just add the property `disabled` to the button, that's it...

Comment: It's just one button tag that displays two buttons. Won't both of them be disabled if I add it?

Comment: No, you are creating two separate buttons with that line, because it is executed twice. For each execution you can have a different result for the conditional and set the `disabled` property depending on that.

Comment: if it's not a bother, can you show me an example of what you mean because I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to express the idea sketched in the comments to the question, as you asked me to and explain it step by step:

```
foreach ($sql1->results() as $set) {
    echo sprintf('<p><button %s>%s</button></p>'."\n", 
        in_array($set->name, array('poodle','cat','sheep')) ? 'disabled' : '',
        $set->name);
}
```

Here `$set` is a different object (set of attributes) for each iteration of the foreach loop. You said you have two entries in that queries result, so two buttons get generated. Each `$set` has a name (`$set->name`) if you understand your code correct (I don't know your database...). This name is used *twice* for generating each button: first the name is used as text in the button and second it is used in a conditional to decide if the button should be disabled or not. That condition is implemented as a trinary expression, line 3 in the example above. In the line a function is called: `in_array()`. That returns true or false. If true, then the attribute "disabled" is added to the button, if false then the empty string ('') is added instead, so the button does *not* have the disabled property.

This is obviously not finished code. It is meant to give you the idea, so you should understand it, not just copy and try it. Feel free to ask if questions arise!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<button class="<?php if($sql1->names != "required_name") echo "disabled" ?>">
<?php echo $sql1->names; ?> 
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried your code and both buttons get disabled. I think because the $sql->names outputs both buttons so if  use it with a query, they both get disabled.

Comment: @Gina I think you're confused… `$sql->names` is just a variable. It doesn't output anything on its own.

Comment: I meant when I echo the $sql->names, it outputs both buttons which is why the above code disables both buttons. Sorry, if i'm missing something here. I have decided to do this another way by just displaying one button.

Answer (score 0):

To disable a button ith php+html, you can try with a query value returned "disabled".
For example: in your query use a CASE WHEN statement to return disabled value when your condition is defined:

```
SELECT filed1,
CASE 
    WHEN field1= '19' THEN 'disabled'
    WHEN field1='20' THEN ''
    WHEN filed1='21' THEN ''
    WHEN field1='22' THEN ''
    ELSE 'disabled'
END AS for_button 
FROM table1 AS tbl1 
WHERE tbl1.field1_param = '$param'
```

Put in the HTML TAG button this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Button OnOff" <?=$disableButton['for_button']; ?>>
```

If the value returned is *disabled*, in the for_button variable, write the valure returned from query and the button will are disabled.